# $.ajax not sending data to my demo.php file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send data to demo.php file but it's not working.

My code is:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function update(str)
    {
        var str2=str;
        $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
            url:'demo.php',
            asyc: true,
            data:'id='str2,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<?php include 'demo.php' ?>
```

And the demo.php:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['id'];
?>
```

Comment: change  data:'id='str2, to  data:'id='+str2,

Comment: Where are you calling the function `update()`?

Comment: update `data:'id='str2,` with `data:'id='+str2,` there is error while concat

Comment: Thansk for the answers. I changed the data but it's not working. I call update from a select onchancge.

Answer (score 2):

Please use below syntax for `data` parameter

```
function update(str)
    {
        var str2=str;
        $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
            url:'demo.php',
            asyc: true,
            data:{id:str2},
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried, but it's not working. I can't echo the id.